# Get total number of name field from JSON within PHP

Tags: php, html, json

Rather new to using json with php, bit of a last resort having searched over the net quite a bit already.  I have this example ison file below, which I wish to be able to echo the total number of 'name:' fields within it so eg. 4 in the example below.

Question:  How would I go about doing this?

```
    [
      {
        "age": "22",
        "name": "Dave"
      },
      {
        "age": "21",
        "name": "Alan"
      },
      {
        "age": "19",
        "name": "Luke"
      },
      {
        "age": "30",
        "name": "Nina"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there will always be a name in each array then just:

```
echo count(json_decode($json, true));
```

If name may or not be present in each array then:

**PHP >= 5.5.0:**

```
echo count(array_column(json_decode($json, true), 'name'));
```

**PHP < 5.5.0:**

```
$count = 0;
foreach(json_decode($json, true) as $k => $v) {
    isset($v['name']) ? $count++ : $count;
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: Your second example should be under **PHP < 5.5.0**